# System.VisualforceException: Invalid value for property label: null

Tags: apex, unit-test, dynamic-visualforce

Sigh. So I am required to cover my Apex code with tests.

I'm testing a piece of code that dynamically builds a tree of controls with a PageBlock as the root object. This code works fine when NOT called from a test.

When this code is called from a test, the error message as per the title is produced. I suspect that any visual component would have this issue, it just happens that the first control I'm dynamically adding is a SelectList.

```
Component.Apex.SelectList ctl = new Component.Apex.SelectList();
ctl.id = item.name;
ctl.multiselect = false;
ctl.size = 1;
System.debug('ABOUT TO SET LABEL TO \"' + item.label + '\"');
ctl.label = item.label;
System.debug('MANAGED TO SET LABEL OK');
```

The last line never gets hit, and the data in item.label just looks normal. The log looks like this:

```
15:25:09.177 (1177886723)|USER_DEBUG|[82]|DEBUG|ABOUT TO SET LABEL TO "Type Of License"
15:25:09.177 (1177893124)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[82]|System.debug(ANY)
15:25:09.177 (1177901217)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[83]|FieldProps.__sfdc_label()
15:25:09.177 (1177916661)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[83]|FieldProps.__sfdc_label()
15:25:09.178 (1178408276)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[EXTERNAL]|System.VisualforceException: Invalid value for property label: null
15:25:09.178 (1178560531)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
15:25:09.178 (1178650763)|FATAL_ERROR|System.VisualforceException: Invalid value for property label: null
```

Can this be done?

EDIT

In the few minutes since I posted, I ran this in the developer console:

```
@isTest
public class UT_Test {
    @isTest
    public static void TestSomething() {
        Component.Apex.SelectList ctl = new Component.Apex.SelectList();
        ctl.id = 'myList';
        ctl.multiselect = false;
        ctl.size = 1;
        ctl.label = 'My List';
    }
}
```

And sure enough it fails with the 'System.VisualforceException: Invalid value for property label: null'. When the "ctl.label 'My List';" line is commented out, the test succeeds.

So how on earth do I test a large piece of custom APEX code that dynamically creates components?

To package and get my code from my Developer Org into my clients Production Org I HAVE to subject it to unit tests with an AVERAGE of 75% code coverage across code and triggers. I don't mind writing the tests, but come on, at least let me win this one!

Answer (score 1):

The label attribute that was introduced Winter12 fails for most form inputs when in test context

```
    Component.Apex.inputText c1 = new Component.Apex.InputText();
    c1.label = 'test'; // this will fail
```

but this being salesforce, there are exceptions

```
    Component.Apex.inputField i1 = new Component.Apex.inputfield();
    i1.label = 'test'; // this works fine
```

Since creating dynamic components in apex isn't considered idiomatic, I doubt there is an easy way around it.

Answer (score 0):

How important label for your test? If you don't specify label it works. You can remove line  "ct1.label = 'My List';" and it will work.

Comment: It's important. I've simplified the code to illustrate the point easily. The real class under test produces a graph of dynamically created VisualForce components each of which has its label set. I cannot change that code to not set the label of each component, and it would be stupid to add a flag set only when testing, to conditionally set the label. Thanks for showing interest in my problem, I appreciate it.